# Magento Module Working On Localhost But Not Live (Subdomain)

Tags: php, xml, .htaccess, magento

I have a magento installation on my MAMP localhost. The url is localhost/httpdocs/. I have created a module called "quotation" that works on localhost, url: localhost/httpdocs/quotation. The form I have created displays properly. On our test domain, http://proac.ourdomain.com/quotation I have a 404 error. The databases are identical as well as the code (synched with PHPSTORM)

On the test domain, the quotation module shows 404, not found, but works locally. Any ideas why this is?

Config.xml

```
    <?xml version = "1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <No_Quotation>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </No_Quotation>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <quotation>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>No_Quotation</module>
                    <frontName>quotation</frontName>
                </args>
            </quotation>
        </routers>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <No_Quotation>
                    <files>
                        <default>Mage_Contacts.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </No_Quotation>
            </modules>
        </translate>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <quotation>
                    <file>quotation.xml</file>
                </quotation>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <quotation_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>No_Quotation</module>
                </setup>
            </quotation_setup>
        </resources>
        <template>
            <email>
                <quotation_email_email_template translate="label" module="quotation">
                    <label>Quote Form</label>
                    <file>quotation_form.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </quotation_email_email_template>
            </email>
        </template>
        <helpers>
            <quotation>
                <class>No_Quotation_Helper</class>
            </quotation>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <No_Quotation>
                    <files>
                        <default>No_Quotation.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </No_Quotation>
            </modules>
        </translate>
    </adminhtml>
    <default>
        <quotation>
            <quotation>
                <enabled>1</enabled>
            </quotation>>
            <email>
                <recipient_email><![CDATA["marcstevenplotz@gmail.com"]]></recipient_email>
                <sender_email_identity>custom2</sender_email_identity>
                <email_template>quotation_email_email_template</email_template>
            </email>
        </quotation>>
    </default>
</config>
```

Module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <No_Quotation>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </No_Quotation>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: It's probably in you Controller and not the config files. Paths logic is <frontname>/<controller>/<action> and always try to dump the cache folder.

Comment: But why would it work locally and not on the live server?

Comment: Could be the way you use casing, Linux and windows have don't follow the same rules. Take a look at http://www.sharpdotinc.com/mdost/2009/03/19/magento-module-not-working-on-unixlinux-server/ Addtionaly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7429825/magento-controller-works-windows-not-linux check your server settings

Comment: I'm on mac, MAMP, not windows. Casing is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I hope ,it is issue in config.xml `spacing issue`:
I have seen  your,there are `some space below start` of     `<?xml version = "1.0"?>`,SO remove this space

Comment: That was due to copy and paste, I checked and there are no spaces.